# Many navigationControllers to one viewController, all inside a tabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

**The basic layout of storyboard:**

The apps master view is a tab bar view with 5 tab options as root views of their own navigation controllers.

Three of the 5 tab bar `viewControllers` will be able to navigate to a detailed description view, this view will generally be the same regardless of which `tabController` it is navigated from.

See the image below...

[image: Storyboard Layout Slice]

**The Question:**

Do I have to have a separate copy of each `detailedViewController` for each `tabBarController`  navigation flow? Or is there a way that one `viewController` can be made and used in multiple `navigationController` flows?

How would I let the `NavigationController` know which `tabController` flow to return to if the back button is pushed?

Does anyone have any advice about keeping the storyboard from becoming chaotic while connecting to many `tabBarViews` to one view?

What complications may I run into because of having the same screen inside multiple navigation Controller?

Comment: Actually, you are doing the right thing, and I don't see any issues here. Since navigation controller maintains correct navigation stack, we don't need to worry about the view to go back from this detail view controller.